# Permission denied while opening sockets from docker even if root

Tags: linux, docker, sockets, permissions

Somehow I corrupted a docker installation on a Ubuntu Jammy bare metal environment and now I'm trying to figure out what happened.

Let's say that `cat /root/sock.py` gives you

```py
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

Now, while **logged as root to the host machine**, commanding

```
$ whoami
root
$ docker run -it --rm -v /root/:/root-host:ro xnext/xis20 python3 /root-host/sock.py
```

Gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sock.py", line 8, in <module>
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 231, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I'm able to solve the problem adding the infamous `--privileged` flag, which actually ends up with a container in the desidered state, blocked on `accept()`.

But what happened exactly to the host ? Why acting as `root` should encounter any permission issue?

Additional info:

```
$ grep docker /etc/group
docker:x:120:pbertoni
```

`pbertoni` is a user of mine which also belongs to `sudo` group and shares this problem.

```
$ docker run -it --rm xnext/xis20 bash -c "id -u && id -g"
0
0
```

And custom installation directory

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "data-root": "/mnt/data_ssd/docker",
  "runtimes": {
    "nvidia": {
      "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
      "runtimeArgs": []
    }
  }
}
```

Which:

- is readable/writable
- is stored on a mounted ext4 device
- cannot be moved because the `/` is mounted as read-only
- this exact configuration is shared with many other installations and shall not be part of the problem

I even tried to purge and reinstall `docker.io`, without success.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep docker
ii  docker.io                              20.10.25-0ubuntu1~20.04.2         amd64        Linux container runtime
```